# LookupError: No installed app with label "admin"

Tags: python, django, django-countries

So I'm trying to run my development server using the command "python manage.py runserver" 
But whenever I try to run it, it gives me this error;

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 125, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_countries'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 155, in get_app_config
    return self.app_configs[app_label]
KeyError: 'admin'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 579, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 564, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 272, in run
    get_resolver().urlconf_module
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 125, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "F:\Users\Kasutaja\Documents\Veebipood v4\django-ecommerce\djecommerce\urls.py", 
line 6, in <module>
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 256, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 529, in _setup
    AdminSiteClass = import_string(apps.get_app_config('admin').default_site)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 162, in get_app_config
    raise LookupError(message)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'.
```

I have tried searching for solutions to this problem but nothing seems to be working. There seems to also be a weird issue with django-countries. Whenever I try installing it, it says;

```
    Collecting django-countries
      Using cached django-countries-6.0.tar.gz (617 kB)
      WARNING: Generating metadata for package django-countries produced metadata for project name unknown. Fix your #egg=django-countries fragments.
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): unknown from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6d/7a/4046a82f6f0c7d00ad24b3a4fc30d10c562949bb6cd40ef7f3051ed7e2bc/django-countries-6.0.tar.gz#sha256=cca351f304d18187b6200e1aae381c2902045c33aea5f4da58fd74685b7cd4fc in c:\users\kasutaja\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages

The weird thing with this is, that whenever I try to run "python manage.py makemigrations", it says;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Kasutaja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 125, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_countries'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks in advance,
Nimetu.

Comment: Please see if the admin app is added in the INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Yes, it's installed. The issue is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. Just putting this out there just incase anyone has the same issue. If your project has a requirements.txt file (if it doesn't make one)  and add (If you want to use django-countries)

```
django-countries==5.3.3
```

To it, you can also use the latest version but I chose to use version 5.3.3 in this case. After that run the command

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```